# Android java widget determine if the widget was pinned from the home or pinning shortcut

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget, android-shortcut

Is there a way to determine if the widget was pinned from the home or pinning shortcut?

I would need that when the user tries to insert it from the home or from the pinning shortcut, he either doesn't allow it or opens the app to request a text and then allows the widget to be added.

Being that the use of the widget depends on this text and this text is passed via `Intent.ACTION_SEND`, if I don't have this text the widget cannot work.

For example how does `Gmail` o `Outlook` with its widget if you have more than one email.

Home:

[image]

App:

Menu that appears by holding down the app icon for a long time, and then clicking on the word widget

[image]